# Pair key of object and child value with each other for array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that I am attempting to rearrange.

I've tried a combination of `Object.keys()`, and `Object.values()`, and `.map()`, but have not been able to find a solution.

```
let samples = [
  {
    Nitrogen: { units: "mg/L", value: 2 },
    Phosphorus: { units: "mg/L", value: 4 }
  }, {
    Nitrogen: { units: "mg/L", value: 2 },
    Phosphorus: { units: "mg/L", value: 4 }
  }
]
```

Hoping to take the child value of each item in the array and move it up a level.

Expected Result:

```
let samplesValues = [
  { Nitrogen: 2, Phosphorus: 4 },
  { Nitrogen: 2, Phosphorus: 4 }
]
```

Comment: examples of code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over each object.

```js
const samples = [{Nitrogen: {units: "mg/L", value: 2}, Phosphorus: {units: "mg/L", value: 4}}, {Nitrogen: {units: "mg/L", value: 2}, Phosphorus: {units: "mg/L", value: 4}}];

const out = samples.map(obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    const { value } = obj[key];
    return {...acc, [key]: value };
  }, {});
});

console.log(out);
```

Edit: yes, and it's quite a neat trick. You simply assign `value` a default of `obj[key]`.

```js
const samples = [{sampleID: 1, Nitrogen: {units: "mg/L", value: 2}, Phosphorus: {units: "mg/L", value: 4}}, {sampleID: 2, Nitrogen: {units: "mg/L", value: 2}, Phosphorus: {units: "mg/L", value: 4}}];

const out = samples.map(obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    const { value = obj[key] } = obj[key];
    return {...acc, [key]: value };
  }, {});
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I see.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When using map, and returning a variable as `key`, always use `[key]`

```js
let samples = [{
  Nitrogen: {
    units: "mg/L",
    value: 2
  },
  Phosphorus: {
    units: "mg/L",
    value: 4
  }
}, {
  Nitrogen: {
    units: "mg/L",
    value: 2
  },
  Phosphorus: {
    units: "mg/L",
    value: 4
  }
}]

let sampleValues = samples.map(sample => {
  const keys = Object.keys(sample);
  return keys.map(key => {
    return {
      [key]: sample[key].value
    };
  });
})


console.log(sampleValues);
```

Comment: Not quite. Check your output against the expected output.